# Ionic Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list on emulator

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Ionic throw `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` on the `emulator` , but it works fine with `serve` command :

```
Fetch(what, callbackf) {
    return this.woo.getAsync(what).then( (result)=> {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            callbackf(JSON.parse(result.body));
        });
    });
}
```

[image]

the whole provider:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import WooCommerceAPI from 'woocommerce-api';


@Injectable()
export class WooCommerce {

    woo: any = null;

    constructor(public http: Http, private zone: NgZone) {
        this.woo = WooCommerceAPI();
    }

    Fetch(what, callbackf) {
        return this.woo.getAsync(what).then( (result)=> {
            this.zone.run(() => {
                callbackf(JSON.parse(result.body));
            });
        });
    }

}
```

I'm not sure why it's nagging about it , when everything seems to be fine , and it runs with no error/issue on the browser , is there anything am missing here?

here is the `Inoinc` info in case it's related some how!

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: does your callbackf has parameters

Comment: @Nidhinkumar no! 
`this.woo.Fetch('products/categories', (res) => {
                //use res ...
                });`

Answer (score 0):

On what kind of emulator do you try to deploy your app?
I had the same problem on Android 6.0 (API 23) but everything worked fine on Android 7.1.1 (API 25)